# Combining ajax validation with form validation

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces, message

I need two different validations used in this case. The first one is need to be displayed, if the value is not chosen and the form is submitted.

The second one should be validated immediately, when the user chooses “yes” for the answer.
So far, the ajax request works fine, but when no value is chosen, I only get a warning:
(There are some unhandled FacesMessages, this means not every FacesMessage had a chance to be rendered. These unhandled FacesMessages are: … )

I think there is a problem with catching the different messages from the p:selectOneRadio-Tag in the same p:message. Can anyone verify my thoughts? What other possible solutions are there combining these two different type of validations?
Here's the code:

```
<h:form id="formHealtData">
    <p:panelGrid columns="1" 
                 layout="grid" 
                 cellpadding="5">
        <h:outputLabel for="hQuestion1"
                       value="FirstQuestion" />
        <p:selectOneRadio id="hQuestion1"
                          value="#{applicationData.hQuestion1}" 
                          required="true" 
                          requiredMessage="Please answer the question!">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="#{true}" itemLabel="Yes" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="#{false}" itemLabel="No" />
            <f:validator for="hQuestion1"
                         validatorId="trueQuestionValidator" />
            <p:ajax event="change" update="messQ1" />
        </p:selectOneRadio>
        <p:message id="messQ1" 
                   for="hQuestion1" />
    </p:panelGrid>
    <p:commandButton id="next" 
                     value="Next" 
                     action="paymentdata">
    </p:commandButton>  
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

PF `p:commandButton` is ajax by default, this is the reason of your problems.
If you need a normal post, add on commandButton the `ajax="false"` and should work.
If you need ajax then add `update="yourpanelid"` and `process="yourpanelid"` to your elements.